# Labels on a real time flot chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, real-time, flot

I want to add labels on a real time flot chart which takes more than one variables. 
Here is a sample of the code:

```
//...switch code..

case "3":
   dataset = {
                "data1":    {label : "data1", data : dataArray[0]},
                "data2":    {label : "data2", data : dataArray[1]},
                "data3":    {label : "data3", data : dataArray[2]}                                  
            };

    data = [dataset];
    return  data;
    break;
```

The code works perfectly if i will not use labels.
Example below:

```
//...switch code..
case "2":
    data = [
            dataArray[0],
            dataArray[1],
           ];
    return  data;
    break;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Any kind of example or solution will be perfect!

Comment: Could it be that the fact your adding 1 object with objects to the data in case 3 instead of an array of objects? the docs state this: `[ { label: "Foo", data: [ [10, 1], [17, -14], [30, 5] ] },
  { label: "Bar", data: [ [11, 13], [19, 11], [30, -7] ] }
]`

Comment: @VeldMuijz dataArray in this case is just an array with JSON data ( like the other example ) which changes its values dynamically and that is why the chart is a real-time one. So i do not want static data. But i did test it with static data and it still couldn't run..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `data` here is then being used in a `$.plot` call, it's an [incorrect format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format).  You'll end up with an array of a single item, an object with key/value pairs.

What you need is an array of multiple objects:

```
[
  {label : "data1", data : dataArray[0]},
  {label : "data1", data : dataArray[1]},
  {label : "data1", data : dataArray[2]}
]
```

Also, ensure that `dataArray[0]`, etc.. are in the form of an array of arrays:

```
[
  [x1,y1],
  [x2,y2]
]
```